# turn csv file to dict using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have this CSV and I like to structure it in the following format in dict using python. I've tried multiple ways that were suggested but I can't structure them the way I preferred.

example.csv
[image]

```
dist = {1:[1.0], 
        2:[0.5, 0.5], 
        3:[0.2232, 0.5612, 0.2606], 
        4:[0.1465, 0.3202, 0.3606, 0.1727],
        5:[0.1081, 0.195, 0.3444, 0.2222, 0.1303]}
```

Comment: Did you want to ask why your code is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how you can do this:

```
import csv

reader = csv.reader(open('file.csv'), delimiter=',')

next(reader, None)  # to skip the header (first line)

result = dict()

for row in reader:
    if row:
        key = row[0]
        result[key] = row[1:]

print(result)
```

Some explanations:

- `if row:` is here in order to skip empty lines if the csv file contains some empty lines.
- Each row is a `list`, so we choose the first item and set it as a key of the dict
- Finally we select a slice of the list, from the second element to the end, and set it as the value of the key/value pair

Example csv file:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
1,1.0
2,0.5,0.5
3,0.2232, 0.5612, 0.2606
4,0.1465, 0.3202, 0.3606, 0.1727
5,0.1081, 0.195, 0.3444, 0.2222, 0.1303
```

Output:

```
{'1': ['1.0'], 
'2': ['0.5', '0.5'], 
'3': ['0.2232', ' 0.5612', ' 0.2606'], 
'4': ['0.1465', ' 0.3202', ' 0.3606', ' 0.1727'], 
'5': ['0.1081', ' 0.195', ' 0.3444', ' 0.2222', ' 0.1303']}
```

Regarding your comment:
if you want to turn the values to float, just cast them with `float()`.
Replace `result[key] = row[1:]` with:

```
values = row[1:]
values = [float(x) for x in values]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. Can I ask how would you turn all the output's values to int/float?

Comment: I edited my post so you can get floats. But may I suggest you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask ?

Comment: Thank you so much. And, yes, I will. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can use pandas to do so
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html

```py
import pandas

data = pandas.read_csv("path")

#create a dICTIONARY
req_dict = df.to_dict()
```

Comment: This code will not return the desired result. It will return dict of dicts and the values of each dict will be columns' values.